# How to do JOIN ON query using Criteria API

Tags: java, jpa, criteria-api, jpa-2.1

Since version 2.1 JPA supports `join on`. I found few examples how to use `join on` in JPQL but none for Criteria API, and here is my question:

> > Is `JOIN ON` is implemented in Criteria APi? And if yes, Can anyone provide example?

Comment: errm javax.persistence.criteria.Join has an on() method.

Comment: @NeilStockton hmm... seems like i need new glasses, thanks, can you post exampole, so i can accept your answer

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try something like this

```
CriteriaQuery<Person> crit = cb.createQuery(Person.class);
Root<Person> candidateRoot = crit.from(Person.class);
Join<Person, Address> addrJoin = candidateRoot.join(Person_.address, JoinType.INNER);
addrJoin.on({some predicate});
```

filling "{some predicate}" with whatever ON clause you want to impose.