# How to filter both entity and @OneToMany relationship by criteria api

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-data, criteria-api

The following example filters "Entity2" according to the given criteria. However, the List of the @OneToMany relationship remains unfiltered (all entities are included, regardless of whether they match the filter). How to expand the filter so that these are also filtered? In this example entity2.entities1 may only include an Entity1 if the "value" is greater or equals the given one.

(postgres) database structure:

```
table1
-------------------
id character
id_table2 character
value integer

table2                                      
--------------                              
id character                                
name character                              
deletedat timestamp without time zone
```

entity model:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "table1")
public class Entity1 {
  @Id
  private String id;

  @Column(name = "value")
  private Integer value;
  // ...
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "table2")
@Where(clause = "deletedat is null")
public class Entity2 {
  @Id
  private String id;

  @Column(name = "name")
  private String name;

  @OneToMany
  @JoinColumn(name = "id_table1", updatable = false)
  private List<Entity1> entities1;
  // ...
}
```

call and specification:

```
public Page<Entity2> findByFilter(SomeFilter filter) {
  Pageable pageable = //...
  return entity2Repository.findAll(createSpecification(filter), pageable);
}

private Specification<Entity2> createSpecification(SomeFilter filter) {
  return (root, query, criteriaBuilder) -> {
    List<Predicate> predicates = new ArrayList<>();
    predicates.add(criteriaBuilder.equal(root.get("name"), filter.getName()));
    root.join("entities1").on(criteriaBuilder.greaterThanOrEqualTo(join.get("value"), filter.getMinValue()));
    query.distinct(true);
    return criteriaBuilder.and(predicates.stream().toArray(Predicate[]::new));
  };
}
```

I already tired solutions from this questions but without success:

- [JPA Criteria Join OneToMany table where clause does not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41379226/jpa-criteria-join-onetomany-table-where-clause-does-not-work)
- [JPA Criteria Builder OneToMany Restrictions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29145958/jpa-criteria-builder-onetomany-restrictions)
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/48441456/3615209

Comment: Did my answer help you? or do you want me to add something to my answer? otherwise, feel free to accept my answer if you like.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, it's better to define the relationship in both classes.

Therefore, from `Entity1` to `Entity2` there is a `@ManyToOne` relationship and from `Entity2` to `Entity1` there is a `@OneToMany` relationship.

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "table1")
public class Entity1 {
  @Id
  private String id;

  @Column(name = "value")
  private Integer value;

  @ManyToOne
  @JoinColumn(name = "id_table2", referencedColumnName = "id", updatable = false)
  private Entity2 entity2;

  // ...
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "table2")
@Where(clause = "deletedat is null")
public class Entity2 {
  @Id
  private String id;

  @Column(name = "name")
  private String name;

  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "entity2")
  private List<Entity1> entities1;
  // ...
}
```

In the end, you have to return a list of entity1, therefore you can reverse the selection and you can start from entity1. In this way, you can use fetch to avoid extra queries and you can navigate with `get`.

```java
private Specification<Entity1> createSpecification(SomeFilter filter) {
  return (root, query, criteriaBuilder) -> {
    List<Predicate> predicates = new ArrayList<>();
    root.fetch("entity2");
    predicates.add(criteriaBuilder.equal(root.get("entity2").get("name"), 
                                     filter.getName()));
    predicates.add(criteriaBuilder.greaterThanOrEqualTo(
                                             root.get("value"), 
                                             filter.getMinValue()));
    query.distinct(true);
    return criteriaBuilder.and(predicates.stream().toArray(Predicate[]::new));
  };
}
```

Comment: I saw similar solutions in the web. However, I get "The method get(String) is undefined for the type Fetch<>".

Comment: You are right, I changed the solution.

Comment: With the changed solution I get: "Unable to locate Attribute  with the the given name [entity2] on this ManagedType"
I changed it to "entities1", but after that I get: "Unable to locate Attribute  with the the given name [value] on this ManagedType [Entity2]"

"value" is a property of entity1. I also tried root.get("entities1").get("value") as well but this is only supported for 1-1 relationships.

Comment: You have to change the jpa repository that has to be based on `Entity1`.

Comment: Did my answer help you? or do you want me to add something to my answer? otherwise, feel free to accept my answer if you like.