# How to create query using JPA specification on non primary column

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have the below query, where two tables are joining on non primary column. The table is joining on one common column.

In entity, I have not provided any joining between User and UserDetails, and I don't want to provide either

```
SELECT * from User user, UserDetails ud
WHERE user.user_key = :pUserKey // passed in parameter
      user.common_key = ud.common_key
```

**User**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "USER")
@Data
public class User implements java.io.Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    
    @Id
    @Column(name = "user_key", nullable = false)
    @JsonIgnore
    private Long userKey;
    
    @Column(name = "common_key ", nullable = false)
    @JsonIgnore
    private Long commonKey;
}
```

**UserDetails**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "USER_DETAILS")
@Data
public class UserDetails implements java.io.Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    
    @Id
    @Column(name = "user_details_key", nullable = false)
    @JsonIgnore
    private Long userDetailsKey;
    
    @Column(name = "common_key ", nullable = false)
    @JsonIgnore
    private Long commonKey;
}
```

How to achieve the same query in JPA specification

Comment: Please show us User and UserDetails entity

Comment: I have added entity classes

Comment: Why don't you have a relationship between User and UserDetails?

Comment: @Simon Martinelli  This is the primary requirement of my problem, having no relationship, the only common column is there

Comment: You can use join().on() Checkout https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31120461/how-to-do-join-on-query-using-criteria-api

Comment: I have tried that but it is not helping

Comment: So please show us what you tried so far

Comment: @Simon Martinelli I have developed the solution as answered below. Thanks for your time :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have got the solution as expected. I have created new `root` using `query.from()`

Below is the complete solution

```
public static Specification<User> userAndDetails(Long userKey) {
        return (Root<User> root, CriteriaQuery<?> query, CriteriaBuilder builder) -> {
        
            Root<UserDetails> userDetailsRoot = query.from(UserDetails.class);

            Predicate userAndDetailsJoin = builder.equal(
                    root.get(User_.commonKey),
                    userDetailsRoot.get(UserDetails_.commonKey));

            Predicate userKeyPredicate = builder.equal(root.get(User_.userKey),
                    userKey);

            return builder.and(userAndDetailsJoin, userKeyPredicate);
        };
    }
```